# Could Arsenic poisoning be detected in this setting?

Tags: poisons

I have an idea for a story , a detective fiction set in the early 1900's. I have the crime being committed as the title suggests by arsenic poisoning .

I know that Arsenic is a form of poison that a doctor would have to suspect strongly to test for, since the symptoms of poisoning are very akin to stomach related illnesses.

**I would like to know if medicine in the 20th century had advanced enough to actually detect this crime , if the detective in my story points them in this direction .**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding! Unfortunately, asking about historical facts about the real world is explicitly [off-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for here, so I'm flagging it as such

Comment: You might want to read this - [Arsenic's Afterlife: How Scientists Learned to Identify Poison Victims](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/arsenic-s-afterlife-how-scientists-learned-to-identify-poison-victims-excerpt/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"The Marsh test is a highly sensitive method in the detection of arsenic, especially useful in the field of forensic toxicology when arsenic was used as a poison. It was developed by the chemist James Marsh and first published in **1836**."* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh_test))

There were also earlier tests used in forensic examinations in cases of doubtful deaths, for example the Metzger test, the utility of which in forensic examinations was demonstrated by [Valentin Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentin_Rose_(pharmacologist)) in 1806. The most widely used test for arsenic was discovered by [Samuel Hahnemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Hahnemann) (yes, *the* Hahnemann of homeopathic fame -- he was also a good chemist) at the beginning of the 19th century; this test is still in use today.

So, in the end, all this means that at the beginning of the 20th century there was no hope for a criminal to poison their victim with arsenic and escape undetected.